# Not able to see items on Desktop

Tags: 16.04, dconf

I'm using 16.04 and I can't see my items on my desktop. Doing `gsettings set  org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true` in the terminal does nothing and in Dconf show desktop icons is enabled. I know my folder is still on my desktop because `cd /home/desktop` shows it there. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the file/directory not hidden? Hidden file/directory's name start with a "."  . Check if your file/directory/folders name doesnt start with a dot?

Comment: When you run `ls`, do you see you folder listed? If not, then it is a hidden folder, in which case just remove the dot at the start of the name :)

Comment: Linux is case sensitive therefore `Desktop` is not the same as `desktop`. You want the former and it should be under your username. `/home/desktop` is just a folder named `desktop`, not your actual desktop folder, and it has nothing to do with your user.

Comment: It shows up in `ls` and it's not a hidden file either.

Comment: @CelticWarrior `/home/desktop` is my desktop folder, I'm not using xubuntu or any other re-spin I'm using Unity therefor `/home/desktop` is my actual desktop folder, also there is not `/home/Desktop` there is only a `/home/desktop` folder

Comment: No, your desktop folder is `/home/your_username/Desktop` and it has nothing to do with the flavor/variant, they all have the same file structure and so has Debian and pretty much any other distro. Somehow you managed to create a folder named `desktop` inside `/home` (where there should be only users folders or just yours if you're are the only user).

Comment: Please read and understand chapter 3.1.3 with an example from RedHat: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_01.html . All distros pretty much follow the same scheme. Your only "problem" seems to be *not* understanding this.

Comment: alright thank you, I understand. I have deleted the fake desktop folder and moved my files to my actual desktop folder but it still doesn't appear on my desktop. Not even dragging and dropping it on to the desktop seems to be doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Install **gnome-tweak-tool** by typing this in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then you can run **gnome-tweak-tool**, go to **Desktop**, and then turn on the switch in the upper right hand corner.

[image]

I have this problem when using the **Wallpaper** feature **CompizConfig Setting Manager** to control my wallpaper.  Turning on the icons in gnome-tweak-tool restores my desktop icons.

Comment: Nope not working. Nice try.

Comment: Turning it off and then on again worked fine for me.

Comment: I don't even get the `Desktop` entry option

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is a little known glitch in 16.04 that produces an effect similar to the issue you describe. This glitch is activated by moving files from a directory that has a hard linked icon on the desktop.

The most common "fix" for this glitch is to simply:

(1) close or minimize all windows [ Alt+F4 to close individually; Ctrl+Super+D to minimize all windows simultaneously ];

(2) press and hold the Super key until your launcher displays numbers atop its icons;

(3) release the Super key

If this particular glitch is responsible, your desktop icons should immediately become visible. NOTE: This is not a permanent resolution but will work the same way every time it is used.

Comment: Please read the new comments under the question. It's the OP's mistake, that's all.